Freitag-Busam proof of $\sum\limits_{\omega \in L \setminus \{0\}} |\omega|^{-s}$ converges when $s>2$.
One of the main results allowing the possibility of introducing the Weierstrass $\wp$ function is the following:

$\sum\limits_{\omega \in L \setminus \{0\}} |\omega|^{-s}$ converges when $s>2$.

I'm following the proof given by Freitag and Busam's Complex Analysis. Here, they first show that the function
$$
f(x,y):=\frac{|x\omega_1+y\omega_2|^2}{x^2+y^2}
$$
admits a positive minimum on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. This is easy to show. Well, from this fact and from the convergence of
$$
\sum\limits_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{(0,0)\}} \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^\alpha}
$$
for $\alpha>1$ we can conclude.
Now, I do not understand why. I tried something like this: take $2 < \alpha < s$. Then we have
$$
\sum\limits_{\omega \in L\setminus\{0\}} |\omega|^{-s} = \sum\limits_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{(0,0)\}} \frac{1}{\left| m\omega_1 + n\omega_2 \right|^s} 
$$
But I cannot conclude nothing because I'd like to find an upper bound to the last term of the previous equality that is of the form
$$
\sum\limits_{(m,n)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{(0,0)\}} \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^\alpha},
$$
and this seems no possible. How can I solve this problem?

You already know that $f(x, y) \ge c$ for all $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$ with some constant $c > 0$, so
$$
 \frac{1}{\left| m\omega_1 + n\omega_2 \right|^s}
= \frac{1}{f(m, n)^{s/2}} \cdot \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^{s/2}} 
\le \frac{1}{c^{s/2}} \cdot \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^{s/2}} \, .
$$
The series $\sum\limits_{(m, n) \ne (0, 0)} \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^{s/2}}$ is convergent since $s/2 > 1$, so that $\sum\limits_{(m, n) \ne (0, 0)}\frac{1}{\left| m\omega_1 + n\omega_2 \right|^s} $ is convergent by the direct comparison test.
